# Shortern code with AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba

My code works perfectly to return filtered data to three columns of TextBoxes on a form. When I step through it in debug I can see it takes a very long time to execute my newbie (but working) code. I've recorded macros to try to understand how I might do the same thing with an AutoFilter script & therefore have a quicker script but I'm beaten I'm afraid. Could anyone advise me how I could do this, or if I should bother to do this ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, c As Integer, d As Integer
Dim e As Integer, f As Integer, g As Integer
Dim lstrw As Integer, ws As Worksheet
Dim MySerNum As String, MyLocation As String
Dim MySearchValue As String, MyStatus As String

    MySearchValue = "x" 'search column for cells that contain only the letter "x" 
    Set ws = Sheets(2)
                       'The user will type an "x" in column N at the rows...
                       'he wishes to return data from to the form TextBoxes
    lstrw = ws.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                       'find how many cells contain string "x"
    For f = 1 To lstrw
        If ws.Cells(f, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
            e = e + 1
        End If
    Next f
                       ' loop to find occurrence of "x" and load variables
    For i = 1 To lstrw
                      'the adjacent textbox on the form to TextBox1...
                      'is TextBox16 hence the +15 below   
        If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
            MySerNum = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        End If
        If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
            MyLocation = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        End If
        If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
            MyStatus = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
        End If   
        d = c + 15
        g = d + 15
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & c).Value = MySerNum
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & d).Value = MyLocation
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & g).Value = MyStatus
        If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Since your code works, but you're looking to increase performance, this would be a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is for broken code.

Comment: Thank you FreeMan. I didn't know about that forum.

Comment: No problem, a lot of people don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That said - here are a couple of tips:

Change:

```
For i = 1 To lstrw
                  'the adjacent textbox on the form to TextBox1...
                  'is TextBox16 hence the +15 below   
    If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
        MySerNum = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
    If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
        MyLocation = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
    End If
    If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
        MyStatus = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
    End If   
    d = c + 15
    g = d + 15
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & c).Value = MySerNum
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & d).Value = MyLocation
    Me.Controls("TextBox" & g).Value = MyStatus
    If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
        c = c + 1
    End If
Next i
```

To:

```
For i = 1 To lstrw
                  'the adjacent textbox on the form to TextBox1...
                  'is TextBox16 hence the +15 below   
    If ws.Cells(i, 14).Value = MySearchValue Then
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & c).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        d = c + 15
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & d).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
        g = d + 15
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & g).Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
        c = c + 1
    End If   
Next i
```

Doing so removes all the intermediate `My...` variables, so you can delete the `Dim` statements for them. If you need them later, you can set them once at the end of the loop. That will speed things up a bit.

Comment: Thank you for that tip FreeMan. Much obliged to you.